# Inner working of the C standard library

Tags: c, standards

I am interested in the inner working of the standard C library. I found a good book about a possible implementation - but I am looking for a deeper explanation of the whole standard library and the standards (like POSIX) - the definition of these standards in the standard library.

The C drafts are very helpful but not very nice to read. Is there other literature about this topic?

- Standard-Library-P-J-Plauger 1991
- FreeBSD
- GNU man
- C draft(s)

Albertus

Comment: Please reopen. Closing this unilaterally was an abuse of moderator power. I believe this question is perfectly reasonable, answerable in the SO format, and in fact I have an answer which I was blocked from posting by the unfortunate unilateral decision to close.

Comment: @R..: Right, seems the question is now open, tagging you here so you get a notification and see that the question was reopened =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good starting point would be POSIX. The POSIX 2008 specification is available online here:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

It's more accessible (but sometimes less rigorous) than the C standard, and covers a lot more than just the C standard, i.e. most of the standardized parts of Unix-like systems' standard libraries.

If you're interested in implementations, the first thing to be aware of is that the POSIX-described behavior is usually split (by necessity and pragmatic reasons) between the kernel implementation and the userspace libc implementation. A large number of the functions in POSIX (and a few from the C standard) will merely be wrappers for "system calls", i.e. transitions into kernelspace to service the request. On some libc implementations, even finding these wrappers will be difficult, since they're often either automatically generated by the build scripts, and/or unified into a single assembly-language file.

The major (significant amount of non-kernel code) subsystems of the standard library are generally:

- stdio: On glibc, this is implemented by the GNU libio library, which is a unified implementation of C stdio and C++ iostream, optimized so that neither has to be slowed down by being a wrapper for the other. It's a big hack, and the code is difficult to find and follow. Other implementations (especially the BSDs, but also other libcs on Linux) are much simpler and clearer to read. Ultimately they're based on the underlying file-descriptor IO functions like `open`, `read`, etc.
- POSIX threads: On glibc and modern uClibc, this is NPTL. I'm not familiar with the BSDs' thread implementations. Other Linux libcs either lack threads or provide their own implementations based mainly on Linux `clone` and `futex` syscalls.
- Math library: ultimately, almost all of these are based on the old Sun math code from the early 90s, but they've diverged a lot. Fdlibm is a pretty good base approximation of the code used in modern libcs.
- User, group, hostname (DNS), etc. lookups: This is handled through libnss in glibc, and directly in most other libcs.
- Regular expression and glob matching
- Time and timezone handling
- Locale and charset conversion
- Malloc

If you want to get started reading sources, I would recommend not starting with glibc. It's very large and unwieldy. If you do want to read glibc, be aware that lots of the code is hiding under the sysdeps trees and is organized based on the diversity of systems it's applicable to.

Dietlibc is quite readable, but if you read its source, be aware that it's full of common C programming mistakes (e.g. using `int` where `size_t` is needed, not checking for overflows, etc.). If you keep this in mind, it might not be a bad choice, since ignoring lots of possible errors/failures tends to make the code very simple.

With that said, for reading libc source, I would most recommend either one of the BSDs or musl (disclaimer: I am the primary author of musl so I am a bit biased here). BSDs also have the advantage that the kernelspace code is also extremely simple and readable, so if you want to read the kernel code on the other side of a system call, you can do that too.

Comment: Hi

Thank you for this interesting answer (and unblocking). After reading a little bit from the POSIX specification I noticed, that this documentation is much easier to read than the C standard, because it's focused on the standard definition.

For me, the BSD source page/documentation and the musl-library project are two good start-points. The syscall-backend from these libraries are also interesting.

Albertus

Comment: _unified implementation of C stdio and C++ iostream_ - doesn't `g++` provide its own `iostream` implementation?

Comment: @Maxim: Yes, but it's designed so that the classes' binary layout is the same as the binary layout of the structs in glibc stdio, and the same objects are used for both in this case...

Comment: I can only see `__c_file* __basic_file<char>::_M_cfile` and `__c_file*  stdio_sync_filebuf::_M_cfile` and then `typedef FILE __c_file`. I.e. it is still using good-old `FILE*` under the hood. Could you please elaborate _unified implementation of C stdio and C++ iostream, optimized so that neither has to be slowed down by being a wrapper for the other_

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: Sorry I never saw and responded to your comments at the time. Indeed, g++ does provide its own libstdc++, and all the work that went into making GNU libio function simultaneously as C stdio and C++ iostream went to waste (and it's now an ugly burden for glibc). Basically the idea was that they laid out the C structures with function pointers to match what the C++ compiler does with vtables, wrote the functions to take a pointer that could just as well be the implicit this pointer from a C++ call, etc.

Answer (score 5):

In "C: A Reference Manual, Fifth Edition" by Harbison & Steele, the second part of the book is dedicated to the C Standard library (Part 2: chapters 10-24).

http://careferencemanual.com

The Rationale document for C99 didn't cover the C library but the ANSI C89 Rationale covers in its chapter 4. There is a copy of the document here:

http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/title.html

Comment: Hi

Thank you for the reply, the topic about the C89 "definition" is a good help.